# Split an ultrawide display into multiple (virtual) monitors

Tags: windows-10, display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have an ultrawide display, and I have been looking for a way to split this display into multiple (custom res) virtual displays:

For example like this:

[image]

Where the monitor would ultimately act like sectioned off parts.

I have found several software solutions that automatically resize the windows for certain apps to a desired configurable resolution. This is not what I am looking for, as some apps require full-screen capability, these software solutions do not combat this, and the app would ultimately still cover the entire ultrawide monitor.

I am looking for a way that my monitor would be recognized as two separate monitors by the operating system. I have a (relatively new) Nvidia GPU, my monitor also has PBP capabilities, but it seems only for 50/50 of the monitors aspect ratio?

I am running the latest windows 10 by the way.

I love hacky solutions, so if you have any ideas, please throw them my way!

Comment: Have you tried [nVidia Quadro View](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/software/quadro-view/)? I've never tried it, but it seems to allow you to use multiple desktops on one monitor.  I found it searching for "windows 10 nvidia multiple desktops on one monitor".  It might allow you to use full screen apps on only a section of your monitor.  Worth a shot, I would think.

Comment: nVidia software only works on Quadro cards